# Switching picture in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

Hi im having trouble switching picture in JFrame. Im initializing JFrame as black picture, next i want to load a ''sample2.jpg'' to it:

Display.java

```
public class Display extends Canvas  implements Runnable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public static int WIDTH=1280;
public static int HEIGHT=720;
public static final String TITLE = "rainbow";


private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private Render render;
private Screen screen;
private BufferedImage img;
private int pixels[];


public Display(){
    Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();


}


public synchronized void start(){
    if(running) 
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

    //System.out.println("working...");
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try{
        thread.join();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}   

public void run(){

    while(running){
        render();
    }
}

private void render(){
BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
if(bs == null)
{
    createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}
screen.render();
for(int i=0; i<WIDTH*HEIGHT; i++)
{
    pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];

}

Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Display game = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(game);

    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("running ...");

    game.start();
}

}
```

Render.java

```
public class Render {
public final int width, height;
public final int [] pixels;
public static int tick;

public Render(int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    pixels = new int[width * height];
    tick=0;
}

public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset){
    for(int y=0; y<render.height; y++){
        int yPix = y+yOffset;
        if(yPix<0 || yPix >=height){
            continue;
        }
        for(int x=0; x < render.width; x++){
            int xPix = x+xOffset;
            if(xPix < 0 ||yPix >=width){
                continue;
            }
            int alpha = render.pixels[x+y*render.width];
            if(alpha >0)
            {
                pixels[xPix+yPix*width]=alpha;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void drawRainbow(){
    for(int i =0 ; i <width*height;i++){
        pixels[i] = Image.floor.pixels[i];
    }
    //System.out.println("draw rainbow: " + pixels[1200]);

}
}
```

Screen.java

```
public class Screen extends Render {

private Render test;


public Screen(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
    Random random = new Random();
    test = new Render(width,height);
    for(int i=0; i<width*height; i++){
        pixels[i] = 0;
    }


}

public void render(){
    for(int i =0 ; i <width*height;i++){
        pixels[i]= 0;
    }

    test.drawRainbow();
    draw(test,0,0);
}

}
```

Image.java

```
public class Image {
public static Render floor = loadBitmap("/Images/sample2.jpg");

public static Render loadBitmap(String fileName){
    try{
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Image.class.getResource(fileName));
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        Render result = new Render(width, height);
        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result.pixels, 0 ,width);
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("crash");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}

}
```

In function `render` in class Screen, when i do:

```
public void render(){
    for(int i =0 ; i <width*height;i++){
        pixels[i]= Image.floor.pixels[i];
    }

    test.drawRainbow();
    draw(test,0,0);
}
```

image is loading correctly, but i need this image to be set by function ''drawRainbow'' from class Render, how to achieve this?

Comment: This may not be directly related to your problem, but you should absolutely not do drawing this way. Do not explicitly call drawing methods, just override the paintComponent method of the swing object you want to draw on. Then java will handle repainting it as necessary instead of manually inside a for loop.

Comment: @nhouser9, yes, but i need to manipulate some pixels later as accoring to time so i need to store them as an int array. would it be possible with paintComponent?

Comment: it's fine to store them as an int array. Just reference that int array in paintComponent. Storing them as an int array is not a reason that you need to do your drawing in this inefficient way.

Comment: There's still no relationship between the pixel data and the img you're trying to paint...

Comment: I'e got to give thumbs up for this sofwtare here - you managed to circulate the image around in cycles well enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method for creating a Swing GUI is backwards.

Here's a Swing GUI that shows 6 pictures from the Internet.

[image: Image Display]

Here's how you create a Swing GUI.

1. Create a GUI model that holds the image information.  I created an ImageInformation class to hold, you guessed it, the information for one image.  I created a List of ImageInformation to hold all of the images.
2. I created a JFrame to hold all of the Swing components.
3. I put the creation and usage of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  Oracle and I demand that you start all Swing applications on the Event Dispatch thread.
4. I created an image JPanel to hold the image information and a control JPanel  fpr the JRadioButtons.

Here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ImageDisplay implements Runnable {

    private ItemListener listener;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel titleLabel;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private JLabel descriptionLabel;

    private List<ImageInformation> images;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageDisplay());
    }

    public ImageDisplay() {
        this.images = setImageInformation();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Image Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(createImagePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createImagePanel() {
        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
        imagePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ImageInformation defaultImageInformation = images.get(0);

        titleLabel = new JLabel(defaultImageInformation.getTitle());
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imagePanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                defaultImageInformation.getImage()));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageLabel);
        imagePanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        descriptionLabel = new JLabel(defaultImageInformation.getDescription());
        descriptionLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        imagePanel.add(descriptionLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return imagePanel;
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Images"));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        listener = new ImageListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            ImageInformation imageInformation = images.get(i);
            JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(imageInformation.getTitle());
            if (i == 0) {
                button.setSelected(true);
            }
            button.addItemListener(listener);
            group.add(button);
            panel.add(button);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private List<ImageInformation> setImageInformation() {
        List<ImageInformation> images = new ArrayList<ImageInformation>();

        // Here, you would get your images
        Image image1 = getImage("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-vfRL5DamWFs/"
                + "T2nn6D_EUfI/AAAAAAAABB8/Kc9Y33qYWJo/s1600/People-Power.jpg");
        Image image2 = getImage("http://www.jeffjonesillustration.com/images/"
                + "illustration/00601-group-of-people.jpg");
        Image image3 = getImage("http://www.careersusa.com/portals/0/BusinessPeopleImage2.png");
        Image image4 = getImage("http://www.druginfo.sl.nsw.gov.au/images/teens.jpg");
        Image image5 = getImage("http://www.pesconsulting.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/"
                + "2013/03/kevin-thom-2010-people-collage.jpg");
        Image image6 = getImage("http://www.emcdda.europa.eu/attachements.cfm/"
                + "att_77302_EN_young-people-480px.jpg");

        images.add(new ImageInformation(image1, "Image 1",
                "Image 1 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image2, "Image 2",
                "Image 2 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image3, "Image 3",
                "Image 3 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image4, "Image 4",
                "Image 4 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image5, "Image 5",
                "Image 5 Description"));
        images.add(new ImageInformation(image6, "Image 6",
                "Image 6 Description"));

        return images;
    }

    private Image getImage(String fileName) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new URL(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ImageInformation getImageInformation(String title) {
        for (ImageInformation imageInformation : images) {
            if (title.equals(imageInformation.getTitle())) {
                return imageInformation;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public class ImageListener implements ItemListener {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                JRadioButton button = (JRadioButton) event.getItem();
                String labelText = button.getText();
                ImageInformation imageInformation = getImageInformation(labelText);
                if (imageInformation != null) {
                    titleLabel.setText(imageInformation.getTitle());
                    imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageInformation
                            .getImage()));
                    descriptionLabel.setText(imageInformation.getDescription());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class ImageInformation {

        private final Image image;

        private final String title;
        private final String description;

        public ImageInformation(Image image, String title, String description) {
            this.image = image;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

    }
}
```